# How to upload a file using backbone.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, file-upload, upload

I am trying to upload a file using backbone and needs to make an `API` call to server after uploading.

For this we written html code in the following way.

```
  div class="row">
        <form id="dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/planner.in/api/web/freshtimesummary/add/" method="post" class="fileHeight">
            <div class="fallback">
                <input type="file" class="setName button" id="setName" name="upload_tag_data" placeholder="Browse File & Upload">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="upload-button">Upload</button> 
        </form>
    </div>
```

Javascript(backbone) code:

```
function makingPPApiCall(collectionObj,requestData,successCallback,errorCallback,typeOfRequest){
collectionObj.fetch({
    data:requestData,
    "success":successCallback,
    "error":errorCallback,
    type:typeOfRequest
 });
}


//view code
var uploadFilesView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
  events: {
   'submit form':'uploadFile'
 },
 uploadFile:function(event){
   if (event.target.id===this.ui.formId) {
  console.log("Test");
  //making An Api call for summaryChart
   event.preventDefault();
  var successCallback=function(status,response){
    console.log(response);
  };
  makingPPApiCall(makingAPICallForSummaryChartObj,"",successCallback,errorCallback,'POST');
};
}
});
```

getting the following error:

[image]

What I did wrong here,can anyone help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Since your getting 500 internal server error check the server log for the actual error. May be correct values not being passed or when upload the file it throwing some errors.

Comment: @kds what you said,that's right I am not passing correct data. in request header 1 letter missing.Thanks you